# iPhone icon has gloss on the document share options

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I declared my application to accept file types from other apps ([App-RelatedResources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW2))

When doing so, I had to specify which icon to use, and I chose my app icon. I also specified in my info.plist that there should not be gloss on the icon, and indeed there is not on the icon that is on the springboard. However, there IS a gloss on the icon when it appears on the pop up where I select to "open with" my application.

Any ideas which parameters controls this?

Answer (score 0):

For remove a autoglossing, do this steps:

1) Press cmd + 1 in your XCode project

2) Choose your project at left panel -> Choose your Target at middle panel -> Choose Info tab at right panel

3) Click "+" and choose "Icon already includes gloss effects" and set "YES"

Then from your icon must be disabled any autoglossing

Comment: This only works for the actual app icon on the main screen, but when i click on "open in XXX" in another application and mine appears, the icon DOES have the gloss.